# Hilbert Schmidt norm

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-pde

Suppose $Q \in L(U)$ is non negative operator with $Tr Q < \infty$ where $(U, \langle,\rangle)$ is Hilbert space. Suppose that $e_k, k=0...$ is an orthonormal base of $U$ consisting of eigenvectors of $Q$ with $\lambda_k$ eigenvalues.
Suppose that $U_0=Q^{1/2}(U)$ is the Hilbert space with scalar product
$$\langle u,v\rangle_0=\langle Q^{-1/2}u,Q^{-1/2}v\rangle$$
Call $(L_2^0=L_2(U_0,H),||\cdot||_{L_2^0})$ the Hilbert Schmidt operators from $U_0$ to $H$ where $H$ is another Hilbert space.

Then by the Parseval identity
$$||\Psi||_{L_2^0}^2=\sum_{k,h}^\infty |\langle\Psi g_h,f_k\rangle|^2=\sum_{k,h}^\infty \lambda_h |\langle\Psi e_h,f_k\rangle|^2=\sum_{k,h}^\infty  |\langle\Psi Q^{1/2} e_h,f_k\rangle|^2=||\Psi Q^{1/2} ||_{L_2(U,H)}^2$$

Now why does the following hold [Da prato - Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions 1999] ?

$$||\Psi||_{L_2^0}^2=Tr (\Psi Q \Psi^*)$$

where $g_k=\sqrt{\lambda_k}e_k, k=0...$ is an orthonormal base of $U_0$ and $f_k,k=0...$ is an orthonormal base of $H$

Comment: `\langle \rangle` $\langle \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition:
\begin{align}
\|\Psi\|^2_{L_2^0}&=\|\Psi Q^{1/2}\|^2_{L_2(U,H)}=\operatorname{Tr}((\Psi Q^{1/2})^*\Psi Q^{1/2})\\[0.3cm]&=\operatorname{Tr}(Q^{1/2}\Psi^*\Psi Q^{1/2})=\operatorname{Tr}(\Psi Q\Psi^*). 
\end{align}
In case the problem is the apperance of the trace,
$$
\sum_{h,k}|\langle \Phi g_h,f_k\rangle|^2=\sum_h\|\Phi g_h\|^2=\sum_h\langle \Phi^*\Phi g_h,g_h\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(\Phi^*\Phi). 
$$